# when I take out one hard disk from a RAID array, do I have to inserte a new one later?

Tags: linux, hp-proliant

I am using a Proliant server DL380 G4 (kinda old) and I was testing my RAID... just to know if it really works (using the native RAID that comes with the server), so, I took out one hard disk and work great, I turned it off and today I restarted asked me to disable logical disk or accept data loss and enable the logical disk, first time I press disable, so, when it load the OS was not working, so,I reboot and I accepted other option (accept data loss and load logical disk) and it worked fine... the problem now is that the hard disk I removed (that was the first disk) has the light of -> on, and the light of the hard disk is intermitent all time, I dont know why, I am not so familiar with this hard disk, my question is, do I have to do something different to enable it again?? is the RAID still working?  according to the info of the page(http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?prodSeriesId=1143914&objectID=c00263437) is

```
Activity status (for the indicator "->" )
On = Drive activity
Flashing = High activity on the drive or drive is being configured as part of an array
Off = No drive activity

Online status   (for hard disks)
On = Drive is part of an array and is currently working
Flashing = Drive is actively online
Off = Drive is offline.
```

Do I have to wait until the RAID refresh itself or do something more? I am working with Debian 6

Thanks.

Comment: The message about accepting data loss is just telling you that your raid  array is degraded.  you get the option of either booting with the degraded array ( potential data loss)  or booting with that particular volume disabled.  this can make sense to do if you have multiple logical volumes and you need to boot the server but don't need the degraded volume right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I handled G4's, but if memory serves the flashing means the raid-set is now rebuilding it's redundancy.

When done the led-blinking should normalize and you will just see normal disk-activity on all disks in the raid-set, at the same time.

There is raid-software available for Debian that let's you monitor the progress of the raid-rebuild. You can also re-configure the raid-set with it.

See the HP/Proliant Debian Wiki for more info. http://wiki.debian.org/HP/ProLiant

Comment: thank you! I checked the page but the installer is not available, only a firmware, is it necessary to be installed? in case I dont install it will have some problems at the future?

Comment: you need the array-info tool: http://packages.debian.org/array-info